# PHP : Getting data from a different table and account

Tags: php, mysql

I need help in this. I have two user accounts, one for students and one for experts. The student account page sends a question that is parsed and stored within the database. This question is then forwarded to the expert account to view and answer. The answer coming from the expert is then stored inside the database and then forwarded to the student account for the results.

My problem is this. I have a results page that appears once the student has finished entering his/her question and send it to the database. This result page displays the question the student has entered and the answer from the system.

I don't know how to display the answer. I base everything on my row numbers. The questions sent to the database go to tbl_questions and the answers go to tbl_answers. I have another table called tbl_link_qa which connects tbl_questions to tbl_answers by their row numbers. The problem is on display the answers linked to the questions.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that simply be :

```
select <relevant fields> from tbl_link_qa qa 
inner join tbl_answers a on a.answer_id = qa.answer_id
where qa.question_id = :questionId
```

Comment: I'm using these fields: for tbl_questions : q_rec_id and questions and for tbl_answers: a_rec_id and answers and for tbl_link_qa: qrec_id and arec_id

Comment: Yeah, so replace them as needed.